# How to establish VPN connection with two factor authentication from CLI

Tags: bash, linux-networking, command-line-interface, shell-scripting, networkmanager

A VPN connection have to be established on demand from a bash script. GUI needed to enter two factor auth code. If you'll try to execute in terminal:

```
VPN_NAME=$(nmcli con|grep "VPN"|awk  '{print $4}')
nmcli con up $VPN_NAME
```

you will see that all works fine, but same code in bash script not showing Network Manger window.